# How to set texts in a hosts file (found in C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc folder) using command prompt or a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, dos, command-prompt

I want my system to automatically type certain statements in the host file in a sheduled time. To do that I need to execute a batch file which contains the required commands for setting the statements in host file.
What are the syntax required to set statements in a file, specifically a hosts file or a text file.

Comment: Adding is easy with `echo blah >> %windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`. Do you need to remove them later also ?

Comment: Yes i need to remove them later.By the way, what are syntax required for typing statements in the hosts file using cmd

Comment: `type %windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`. the syntax is well explained inside the file.

Comment: If you can't read the hosts file to see what it needs to contain (which is explained very clearly there), why do you think you need to modify it?

Comment: Why do you need to modify the hosts file? In fact some antimalware softwares prevent modification of the hosts file, even when you have permissions, because it can be abused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add a couple of entries to the HOSTS file, when run as administrator:

```
@echo off
attrib -r -a -s -h C:\WINDOWS\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts 1>nul 
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts >> echo 200.100.10.20    www.bogus.com
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts >> echo 200.100.10.22    www.fake.com
```